Should I avoid mentioning that I am a veteran on PhD Applications?
I am applying to Math PhD programs, and in these applications they ask you what sets you apart from other students. Personally I feel that my status as a veteran and current service in the National Guard makes me pretty unique. For example, I have had to balance several competing obligations for the entire duration of my undergraduate career, such as full-time work, professional military education, active duty periods, annual and monthly military training. In spite of all these obligations I still have a decent GPA (3.5), and I am working on 2 research projects which we are close to publishing.
I feel these things set me apart (like for example I've NEVER met a math prof who was a veteran), and they demonstrate my commitment to continuing education in the face of trials/tribulations.
However, I understand that not everyone will see this side of my life in a positive light. Also I worry that someone on the acceptance committee will look at my resume and say "oh wow this guy could never make it in a math PhD program, hes got too much on his plate!"
What do you guys think? Will this help me or harm me in the long run to emphasize my experience as a student veteran and non-traditional student?
EDIT: This is in the context of the US, both in military service and in graduate schools.

For what it's worth, it's likely illegal to discriminate based on your Guard status.

Will you require funding as a TA for this or do you expect to self fund?

Having read applications for my department's math PhD program, and not remembering any question like this, can I ask where you're being asked this question? (Of course, not all application procedures are the same.)

I find it very unlikely that this will play any role in the admission process.

@academic, its typically included as part of the personal essay / intent / statement of goals part of the application. Nearly all of the applications I'm preparing ask for something like this, and its accompanied by the comment: What are your academic goals? What sets you apart from other students? Why do you want to pursue a math PhD? Some programs also have an (optional) diversity statement / essay.

@BryanKrause thats true, but would be virtually impossible to prove discrimination. I'm just worried it might be more trouble than it's worth to include it.

@RudyJD Got it, thanks. Opinions may differ, but my opinion is that mentioning that you're a veteran is fine and is likely to be perceived positively, or at least neutrally. But I wouldn't focus on this too much, or indeed more generally on "what sets you apart". I would spend most of your personal statement discussing your mathematical achievements, interests, and goals.

@academic Thank you very much for your comments and advice, it has given me a better picture of how to approach the task!

Is this in a US context?

@Anyon Yes it is. I will update my post :)

If you're wondering whether someone may say "Well, gee, he's got a lot on his plate already, how could he possibly do a PhD in addition?" then the place to reply to this hypothetical question is right there, in your essay! In applications, if you can anticipate questions, you've got to answer them then and there!

@RudyJD Yes, that's why I qualified it with "for what it's worth". On the one hand, even if you could possibly prove discrimination it's probably not going to be worth your effort to pursue a claim. But on the other hand, admissions decisions are usually by committee, and people on the committee should be aware of what constitutes illegal discrimination and it's very unlikely that anyone would explicitly call it out as a reason to deny admission (and if they did, they'd likely be chastised by someone else on the committee who realizes it's illegal).

@BryanKrause all good points! I guess I keep forgetting it's not just one person who is reviewing an application.

Like you, I can't recall meeting a math professor who was a veteran. However, I'm also pretty sure I've never met a math professor who would hold negative views about someone solely because that person is a veteran, let alone actively discriminate against such a person in an admissions decision, knowing that such discrimination would be blatantly illegal and unethical. Some professors may hold political opinions that lead them to disapprove of militarism, and/or to disapprove of some of the ways in which the US government uses the armed forces; but do some people disapprove of veterans? Really, is this a thing?
Now, whether it would help you to mention it, I can't say. I suspect it wouldn't be perceived as much of a big deal either way; as @academic said in a comment, admissions committees for graduate math programs are mostly interested in why people want to do a PhD in math and why their background prepares them well for this track. Your status as a veteran and the experiences you've had in the military, as much as they may make you an interesting person, do not necessarily make you a more interesting candidate in the context of a math graduate program application. (But maybe some people would think that it does; I really have no strong opinion about this issue, and no particular insight into how people who aren't me think about it.)
Bottom line:

Should I avoid mentioning that I am a veteran on PhD Applications?

No one can guarantee that any specific thing you say about yourself won't tick someone off for some bizarre reason. However, discriminating against you for your veteran status would be illegal, unethical, and illogical. The idea that this is a serious risk seems a bit outlandish to me personally. (As for thinking you have too much on your plate: it's common to accept people who are parents of young children to graduate programs. Need I say more...?)
At the same time, if you do mention it, try not to make it out to be more important than it really is, considering that you are writing in the specific context of an application to a math graduate program. If you present this background information about yourself (or any other background information) in a grandiose, unreasonable way, that could leave a poor impression.
Best of luck with your applications!

It is true that by now those who served in WW2 and Korea and then got PhDs are out of the system (and, sadly, mostly gone including my late father-in-law). There are just fewer out there now (recall that in WW2 10% of the US population was in the armed services). I've hired several veteran PhDs (not math) over the years and more non-PhD veterans. I can pretty much guarantee that a veteran who is in the ballpark for admittance to a PhD will have a clear focus on getting it done combined with an amazing work ethic - they are true adults and know why they are there. Great catch for any professor.

Just mentioning that you are a veteran is neither here nor there. As you mention, a lot of folks in academia have no military background* so "veteran" by itself is just an empty label.
But mentioning your story should have an impact. Not (just) the label, but what that means - that you "had to balance several competing obligations for the entire duration of my undergraduate career, such as full-time work, professional military education, active duty periods, annual and monthly military training" and how this does "demonstrate [your] commitment to continuing education in the face of trials/tribulations".
Sure, there is always the odd chance that some supervisor doesn’t like you for your background. This happens. But in the end, I would consider this a good thing: you are a unique person and shouldn’t waste your time working with someone who doesn’t like you for who you are.

*This can vary strongly by country and I would expect many people just not to tell unprompted. But academia usually gives an advantage to people who commit to academia, so the straight career path without detours tends to be in the majority.
